# How to get around 'device in use' error when preseeding Ubuntu 22.04 install with encrypted LVM

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, encryption, preseed, ubiquity

I am trying to make a custom install ISO for Ubuntu with Cubic and Ubiquity's preseed option. I have been tearing my hair out trying to get it to automatically partition the entire disk as an encrypted LVM like the GUI installer allows one to do. I have tried nearly a dozen example preseed configurations I've found online, all of which end with the installer erroring out during partitioning because:

`No modifications can be made to the device: Encrypted Volume (sda1p2_crypt) for the following reasons: In use by LVM module group crypt` or whatever the recipe has named the LVM group. I assume these recipes worked for prior versions of Ubuntu.

At first, I thought this error was just because the disk has some pre-existing partitioning with encrypted LVMs, so I ran an `sgdisk -Z /dev/sda`, restarted, and retried but the issues persist.

I can, of course, manually partition the disk just fine with the GUI of the installer.

Here's a sample section from the preseed:

```
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string crypt
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select root-encrypted
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      root-encrypted ::                                       \
              500 500 500 ext4                                \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              2000 2000 2000 linux-swap                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ swap }               \
                      in_vg { crypt }                         \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .                                               \
              500 10000 1000000000 ext4                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ rootpart }           \
                      in_vg { crypt }                         \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_mount_point boolean false
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

Another one which produces the same error. In this one, I am not using a custom recipe, instead just opting for the built-in recipe.

```
#Get around the prompt for UEFI-only
d-i partman-efi/non_efi_system boolean true
d-i partman/default_filesystem string ext4

# In addition, you'll need to specify the method to use.
# The presently available methods are:
# - regular: use the usual partition types for your architecture
# - lvm:     use LVM to partition the disk
# - crypto:  use LVM within an encrypted partition
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase password mypassword7
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again password mypassword7

# If one of the disks that are going to be automatically partitioned
# contains an old LVM configuration, the user will normally receive a
# warning. This can be preseeded away...
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
# The same applies to pre-existing software RAID array:
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
# And the same goes for the confirmation to write the lvm partitions.
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# For LVM partitioning, you can select how much of the volume group to use
# for logical volumes.
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max

# You can choose one of the three predefined partitioning recipes:
# - atomic: all files in one partition
# - home:   separate /home partition
# - multi:  separate /home, /var, and /tmp partitions
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation, provided
# that you told it what to do using one of the methods above.
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

What is the partman configuration needed to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive attempts, research, and reading the experiences of others trying to accomplish this, I have come to the conclusion that this is impossible due to some bug in the installer.

The Ubuntu Server iso w/ autoinstall and subiquity can accomplish this quite cleanly with the autoinstall functionality and I would suggest that for anybody as an alternative to going down the rabbit hole of solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [docs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation)

> Preseeding keys for the following installer components will not be used in Ubiquity, usually because they do not fit with Ubiquity's mode of operation:
>
> netcfg
>
> LVM and RAID partitioning
>
> base-installer
>
> pkgsel/tasksel
>
> finish-install

You are right, there is no way to use `LVM/crypto` recipes in `Ubiquity`.